# How to use web.xml or call servlet init() when using GWTTestCase

Tags: unit-testing, gwt

I am using GWTTestCase class and I have to specify any servlets to use in module.gwt.xml file using

```
<servlet path="/somepath" class="com.example.SomeServlet"/>.
```

The actual requirement is to load other servlets that initialize resources (using `GenericServlet.init()` method) in order to make the tests run. web.xml is the obvious choice as this works in normal application setup. Also it would be useful to declare initialisation parameters.

How do I get GWT to read web.xml file when doing unit testing?

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll have to:

1. extend your servlet and override the init() method to pass the appropriate parameters
2. configure that servlet in your `*.gwt.xml` (I'd suggest using a module specifically for the test(s), so that the `<servlet>` don't clutter your *production* module)

As an alternative, because this looks more like an integration test than a unit test, don't use a GWTTestCase but rather WebDriver/Selenium and a lightweight servlet container configured specifically for your test (e.g. Jetty).

Answer (score 0):

I would try Google Guice with its servlet extension. It allow you to dynamically bind servlets instead of web.xml. Real nice. You can load a specific testing module for example. The official docu has examples for the servlet extension. Hopefully it will provide you with what you need.

Comment: Well, how can I install the Guice filter :| ?

Comment: This is an example for this: http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletModule